# Align paired end reads with bwa mem snakemake with fastq as input

Tags: python, python-3.x, workflow, snakemake

I have two lists with fastq files, where each element of the list corresponds to the other (first fastq in list 1 corresponds to first fastq in list 2 and so on).

My Snakefile so far looks something like this:

```
fastq1_list = [
    "/user/cfDNA_test_pipeline/patients/snakemake_test/test_fastq/test_004_T1T2_1.fastq.gz",
    "/user/cfDNA_test_pipeline/patients/snakemake_test/test_fastq/test2_005T1T2_2_1.fastq.gz"
    ]


fastq2_list = [
    "/user/cfDNA_test_pipeline/patients/snakemake_test/test_fastq/test_004_T1T2_2.fastq.gz",
    "/user/cfDNA_test_pipeline/patients/snakemake_test/test_fastq/test2_005T1T2_2_2.fastq.gz"
    ]

patient_list = [
    "patient004",
    "patient005"
]

timepoint_list = [
    "T1T2",
    "T1T2"
]

rule all:
    input:
         
        sorted_bam = expand(path+"/{patient}/{time}/plasma.sorted.bam", zip, patient=patient_list, time=timepoint_list),


rule align_plasma:
    input:
         fastq1 =fastq1_list,
         fastq2 = fastq2_list,
         reference = reference

    output:
          sorted_bam = path+"/{patient}/{time}/plasma.sorted.bam"

    threads: 8

    shell:
         '''
         bwa mem -t {threads} -T 0 {input.reference} {input.fastq1} {input.fastq2}  | samtools sort -@ {threads} -O BAM {output.sorted_bam} 
             
         '''
```

I was hoping that when executing this file snakemake would iterate through `fastq_list1` and `fastq_list2` align the according fastq files together. This means executing a command similar to this one.

```
bwa mem -t 8 -T 0 ref-genome.fa user/cfDNA_test_pipeline/patients/snakemake_test/test_fastq/test_004_T1T2_1.fastq.gz /user/cfDNA_test_pipeline/patients/snakemake_test/test_fastq/test2_004T1T2_2_1.fastq.gz  | samtools sort -@ 8 -O BAM user/cfDNA_test_pipeline/patients/snakemake_test/patient004/T1T2/plasma.sorted.bam
```

And then go on to the next element in the list and produce the bam file for patient005.

Instead Snakemake substitues `{input.fastq1}` and `{input.fastq2}` with all elements of the respective list.

If anybody could point out how I can achieve what I actually want (pairwise iterate through fastq1_list and fastq2_list and align each file), I would be very thankful!

Cheers!

Comment: It may be more helpful for you to arrange you data in a tab separated file. You can then use pandas to import this file and access the fastq files for each patient - time combination. An example of this is given in the snakemake documentation [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#tabular-configuration)

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate how this solves my problem?
I converted my data to a dataframe, but the same problem still occures. It uses all fastq files simuntaniously, and not just the ones which correspond to the patient-time combination.